# Deserialize RestClient response Enum Conversion Error - The JSON value could not be converted to Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, enums, restsharp

In our asp.net application, we recently upgraded from restsharp 106.12.0 to 110.2.0.
There were no issues with the old version, but after upgrading with few changes to code, we are getting the errors:

> The JSON value could not be converted to
> SubExCore.Models.Enums.YearType. Path: $.body.YearType | LineNumber: 0
> | BytePositionInLine:
>
> The JSON value could not be converted to
> System.Nullable`1[SubExCore.Models.Enums.SectionType]. Path:
> $.body.sectionType | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine

Here is my api method to get YearBook response by deserializing json response response.

```
        public YearBook GetYearBook()
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(MethodType)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
                Resource = ApiPath,
                Method = Method.GET,
                JsonSerializer = new CustomJsonSerializer()
            };
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json, Resource = ApiPath, Method = Method.Get };
            var options = new RestClientOptions()
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri(BaseAddress),
                CachePolicy = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true, NoStore = true }
            };
            RestClient client = new RestClient(options);
            if (!Token.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "authToken " + Token);
            }
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            var myresonse = client.Execute<YearBook>(request);
            return myresonse.Data;
        }
```

Here is my YearBook class with Enum property

```
[Table(TableName = "tblYearBook")]
public class YearBook
{
    [Map(ColumnName = "year_id"), Key]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Map(ColumnName = "year_type")]
    public YearType YearType { get; set; }

    [Map(ColumnName = "section_type")]
    public SectionType? Section { get; set; }

    [Map(ColumnName = "college_name")]
    public string CollegeName { get; set; }

    [Map(ColumnName = "avg_pass")]
    public decimal AvgPass { get; set; }
}

public enum YearType
{
    FirstYear,
    SecondYear,
    ThirdYear
}

public enum SectionType
{
     None,
     MIT,
     BIT
}
```

Here is the json response i get from the method.

```
{
    "year_id": "2005",
    "year_type": "FirstYear",
    "section_type": "None",
    "college_name": "St. Alphores Govt College",
    "avg_pass" : 89
}
```

Earlier we have CustomSerializer implemented out of RestSharp.Serializers.ISerializer. The new Restsharp version now implementing the customserializer from IRestSerializer. There is no enough detail in Restsharp documenation neight on internet.
Could anyone give me a proper implementation of IRestSerializer which has below serialization settings.

Here is my existing custom serializer class with Restsharp version 106.12.0

```
public class CustomJsonSerializer : RestSharp.Serializers.ISerializer
    {
        public CustomJsonSerializer()
        {
            var restSerializer = new RestSharp.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer();
            this.ContentType = restSerializer.ContentType;
        }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string DateFormat { get; set; }
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public string RootElement { get; set; }
        private JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings
        {
            get
            {
                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                settings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeJsonConverter());
                settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                return settings;
            }
        }
        string RestSharp.Serializers.ISerializer.Serialize(object obj)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, SerializerSettings);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *`The JSON value could not be converted to SubExCore.Models.Enums.YearType. Path: $.body.YearType | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine:`* -- this error message is in the format generated by **System.Text.Json**, not Json.NET.  So this is the serializer you are actually using.  Try applying `[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter)]` to `public SectionType? Section { get; set; }` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Also, you wrote, *The new Restsharp version now implementing the customserializer from IRestSerializer.* -- please share a [mcve] showing how you are configuring this customserializer.

Comment: Incidentally your JSON looks to be snake_case but your Json.NET config options are for camel case.  You must be expecting that the `[Map(ColumnName = "year_id"), Key]` attributes configure the name, but where does `MapAttribute` come from?  I can't find it in the RestSharp source code.

Comment: @dbc: MapAttribute is our custom class extended out of Attribute abstract class.

Comment: I get that using the [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter)] attribute for enum property resolved the issue. BUT we have hundreds of models with enum and date properties, I want a custom serializer to take care of the deserialization while getting the response from RestSharp.RestClient, instead attributing all the models in the project.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically how you are currently initializing your RestClient.  It would also help if you shared how you were previously initializing your `RestSharp.Serializers.ISerializer`, because it sounds like your real problem is with upgrading your RestSharp version.

Comment: @dbc: Updated the question with the Custom serializer class we use for 106.12.0 RestSharp. Serializer will be assigned to request object. (JsonSerializer = new CustomJsonSerializer()).

FYI, DateTimeJsonConverter is a custom serializer inherited from JsonConverter abstract class.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in suggesting how to port your code to RestSharp 110.2.0 because the code shown doesn't work.  1) The code for `GetYearBook()` doesn't compile, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/4S6yoI.  2) Your difficulty is with deserialization, but you never share your [`IDeserializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/106.12.0/src/RestSharp/Serializers/IDeserializer.cs), only your `ISerializer`.  3) The JSON shown in **snake case** but your `ISerializer` generates **camel case** for`YearBook`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HeiHYi.

Comment: If you can share working deserialization code that successfully deserializes a `YearBook` from the JSON shown in RestSharp version 106.12.0.0, then we can help to port it to 110.2.0.  But without knowing how your deserialization code works in 106.12.0 -- most particularly, how you are deserializing snake case using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` -- your question looks unanswerable.  The only thing we could tell you is how to use Json.NET in RestSharp 110.2.0.

Comment: public YearBook GetYearBook()
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest()
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
                Resource = ApiPath,
                Method = Method.GET,
                JsonSerializer = new CustomJsonSerializer()
            };
   
            RestClient client = new RestClient {BaseUrl = new Uri(BaseAddress)};   
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            var myresonse = client.Execute<YearBook>(request);
            return myresonse.Data;
        }

I fixed ur code.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i simplified class and using provided pieces created example for you

```
void Main()
{
    string j = "{\"year_id\":\"2005\",\"year_type\":\"FirstYear\",\"section_type\":\"None\",\"college_name\":\"St. Alphores Govt College\",\"avg_pass\":89}";
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j, SerializerSettings).Dump();
}

public class YearBook
{
    [JsonProperty("year_id")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("year_type")]
    public YearType YearType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("section_type")]
    public SectionType? Section { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("college_name")]
    public string CollegeName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("avg_pass")]
    public decimal AvgPass { get; set; }
}

public enum YearType
{
    FirstYear,
    SecondYear,
    ThirdYear
}

public enum SectionType
{
     None,
     MIT,
     BIT
}

private JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings
{
    get
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        settings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeJsonConverter());
        settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        return settings;
    }
}

class DateTimeJsonConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateTimeJsonConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

as you see, string response deserialized to object as expected:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the effort.
As i mentioned we are using RestSharp client to get the response and serialize/deserialize the json data. Using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j, SerializerSettings) is working for me too. 
RestSharp had the option to write custom serialization/deserialization method. After the upgrade these methods were deprecated.
If you can proivde the same serialization in RestSharp way will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Power Mouse tells you how to configure NewtonsoftJson to handle the JSON and the model from the question.

In order to use it with RestSharp, you need to tell it to use these settings.

Assuming you have a class for some API client, it can look like

```cs
class SomeApiClient {
    readonly IRestClient _client;

    public SomeApiClient() {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        settings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeJsonConverter());
        settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        var options = new RestClientOptions { ... something here };
        _client = new RestClient(
            options, 
            configureSerialization: cfg => cfg.UseNewtonsoftJson(settings)
        );
    }
}

class DateTimeJsonConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateTimeJsonConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

It's described in the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net), all it takes is to look.